# Can I use windows 7 route command to use my pc as a network router?

Tags: windows, networking

I am trying to use my PC as a router so that one network can access another (not only PC),

1. I have One NIC with IP 172.20.10.180 , Subnet 255.255.255.0
2. I have another NIC with IP 172.20.110.70 , Subnet 255.255.255.0

Here using my PC, I can access both networks but I want to connect these two networks.

Is It possible?

I have tried to use window routing table by using window route command . But it is not working.
I have also tried to bridge them but as per my understanding i cant bridge different network.

Is there any solution? Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a routing feature in Windows, the following article is for windows XP but it should work on 7 as well: http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Windows-XP-Routing

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.